# phpmyadmin blank page - getCookie error when 'php index.php'

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

when accessing the www.hostname/phpmyadmin/ page i get the blank page. Tried to reinstall PHP,HTTPD and MYSQL.
After running php index.php in the phpmyadmin folder I get the following error:

```
[root@ansible1 phpmyadmin]# php index.php 
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getCookie() on null in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Url.php:219
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Url.php(171): PhpMyAdmin\Url::getCommonRaw(Array, '?')
#1 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Core.php(762): PhpMyAdmin\Url::getCommon(Array)
#2 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Core.php(338): PhpMyAdmin\Core::linkURL('https://secure....')
#3 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Core.php(364): PhpMyAdmin\Core::getPHPDocLink('book.json.php')
#4 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Core.php(1006): PhpMyAdmin\Core::warnMissingExtension('json', true)
#5 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/common.inc.php(110): PhpMyAdmin\Core::checkExtensions()
#6 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/index.php(23): require_once('/usr/share/phpm...')
#7 {main}
  thrown in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Url.php on line 219
```

**On the line 219 in the corresponding file:**

```
 public static function getCommonRaw($params = [], $divider = '?')
    {
        /** @var Config $PMA_Config */
        global $PMA_Config;
        $separator = Url::getArgSeparator();

        // avoid overwriting when creating navi panel links to servers
        if (isset($GLOBALS['server'])
            && $GLOBALS['server'] != $GLOBALS['cfg']['ServerDefault']
            && ! isset($params['server'])
            && ! $PMA_Config->get('is_setup')
        ) {
            $params['server'] = $GLOBALS['server'];
        }

        if (empty($PMA_Config->getCookie('pma_lang')) && ! empty($GLOBALS['lang'])) {
            $params['lang'] = $GLOBALS['lang'];
        }

        $query = http_build_query($params, '', $separator);

        if ($divider != '?' || strlen($query) > 0) {
            return $divider . $query;
        }
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong but havent found this error on the internet....
The blowfish secret is set:

```
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'H2OxcGXxflSd8JwrwVlh6KW6s2rER63i';
```

Any idea what could I be missing? Even a hint what direction to look will be appreciated.

EDIT1:

Downgraded to version 4.9.4 - getting the similar error:

So after downgrading to version 4.9.4 I get the very similar....

```
[root@ansible1 phpmyadmin]# php index.php 
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getCookie() on null in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Url.php:217
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Url.php(169): PhpMyAdmin\Url::getCommonRaw(Array, '?')
#1 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Core.php(749): PhpMyAdmin\Url::getCommon(Array)
#2 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Core.php(330): PhpMyAdmin\Core::linkURL('https://secure....')
#3 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Core.php(353): PhpMyAdmin\Core::getPHPDocLink('book.json.php')
#4 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Core.php(987): PhpMyAdmin\Core::warnMissingExtension('json', true)
#5 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/common.inc.php(106): PhpMyAdmin\Core::checkExtensions()
#6 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/index.php(27): require_once('/usr/share/phpm...')
#7 {main}
  thrown in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Url.php on line 217
```

The page now shows: Access Denied - simply written, no pictures or anything.

What am I missing? :/

[Browser view[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XSyy.png)

Comment: doesnt find this `getCookie('pma_lang')` in your `getCommonRaw()` function

Comment: Maybe you forgot `include some file` ?

Comment: You seem to be using an old version of phpmyadmin.  You should download the latest version and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Dilek: See line 15, maybe You missed it....

Comment: Patrick: It should be version 5.0.1 - newest according to oficial webpage... downloaded as in tutorial this way:

DATA="$(wget https://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/version.txt -q -O-)"
URL="$(echo $DATA | cut -d ' ' -f 3)"
VER="$(echo $DATA | cut -d ' ' -f 1)"

Comment: curl -o phpMyAdmin-${VER}-english.tar.gz  https://files.phpmyadmin.net/phpMyAdmin/${VER}/phpMyAdmin-${VER}-english.tar.gz

Comment: There's more recent changes in their master branch on github, but it may not be considered "stable".  Still might be worth trying.  Or open [open an issue](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues) with them.

Comment: So after downgrading to version 4.9.4 I get the very similar....

Comment: Wait, I just realized that you're running this from the command line (`[root@ansible1 phpmyadmin]# php index.php`).  Why?  phpmyadmin is meant to be run from a browser.

Comment: Patrick, I did that to debug it -- see the screenshot from browser in edited post

Comment: @bisan11  I'd say that's more of a permissions issue and unlikely unrelated to what you're seeing on the command line.  As I mentioned, unless you're running the specific [CLI version](https://github.com/fdev/phpmyadmin-cli) (functional but originally done as a joke), phpmyadmin is not meant to be run (and should not be expected to run properly) from the command line.

Comment: You should check you php error logs to see if they provide any more detail into exactly what access is being denied.  It could be a file permission issue, or it could be a mysql user/password issue, or maybe something else.  Also, it probably won't help, but just for kicks I would try using the full path `phpmyadmin/index.php` instead of just pointing to the `phpmyadmin/` directory.

Comment: Thanks Patric - I see your point. Nevertheless I have no idea what to check, tried chmod 777 on whole phpmyadmin folder to see if it helps - but stays the same. Now reverting.

Comment: Seems You are correct... from httpd error log now I see:

Got error 'Unable to open primary script: /usr/share/phpmyadmin/index.php (Permission denied)\n'
 its strange because of full permissions but gives me something to stick to

Comment: @bisan11  I probably can't help you much further, but I suggest checking out [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/550871/no-input-file-specified-unable-to-access-phpmyadmin-using-debian-squeeze), [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/670936/fastcgi-sent-in-stderr-unable-to-open-primary-script), and [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/928561/fastcgi-unable-to-open-primary-script-on-nginx-and-php-fpm)

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if my previous post is visible, so I post it again:

I had the same error message, and row #4 says: "PhpMyAdmin\Core::warnMissingExtension('json', true)".

After installing php-json package, problem was solved for me.

Comment: I've been looking for this answer for hours.. thank you

Comment: Note that with phpMyAdmin 5.1.2 the error is "Call to a member function get() on null "
Installing phpMyAdmin 4.9.9 gave me the "Call to a member function getCookie() on null " error and i found this topic with the correct solution.